# Wordpress Spam Text Issue

Tags: php, wordpress

When I share a link from my website, It always appear following text.

**"Want create site? Find Free WordPress Themes and plugins. Did you find apk for android? You can find new Free Android Games and apps."**

How can I fix this? I have already tried plugins to scan, But nothing worked, How can I find this in my theme files? and remove it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening is the Spam Text is not even hosted on your Wordpress but rather when you send an email it triggers a function either in the database or file that then sends a request to a spam host that then relays response.

Best way would be to listen to all requests being sent when you send an email either tailing or simply using a plugin to check ..

Also Check your Meta SEO data - description and keywords of your website ..

Comment: This is what I have in my header.php

<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
 <?php
 if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false)) {
  echo('<meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">');
 } ?>

Comment: That Looks fine to me, give me access to your platform if you don't mind. My Portfolio github.com/Peace-N